# Using a list of tuples on a function which take tuples

Tags: python

I want to use a function which takes tuples as an argument, however I have a list of tuples and whenever I try feeding the list of tuples to the function it returns

```
 s = s.join(x)
 TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

However with just one tuple on its own without a list around it, the function will work as expected.

Is there a way in which I can feed a list of tuples like this:

```
[('abcd','1234','xyz'),('e.t.c', 'e.t.c', 'test')]
```

to a function which takes single tuples on their own? Thanks :)

EDIT - 
This is the function I am feeding the list of tuples to:

```
def strFormat(x):

  #Convert to string
  s=' '
  s = s.join(x)
  print(s)

  #Split string into different parts
  payR, dep, sal, *other, surn = s.split()
  other = " ".join(other)

  #Print formatting!
  print ("{:5}, {:5} {:>10} {:10} £{:10}".format(surn , other, payR, dep, sal))
```

When putting a single tuple to this function it returns the print formatted string as expected. When putting a list of tuples to this function it does not work and returns an error. How do I make it so a list of tuples like the one above will work on the above function?

Comment: And what would the expected outcome be? I note that you appear to be calling `str.join()`, but your sample list of tuples doesn't contain strings. Can you give us a [mcve] please?

Comment: the function I am trying to feed the tuples to converts them to a string and then uses print formatting to make a neat table of the results. I made a mistake with the samples tuples in the question, they are tuples of strings.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen to each of these tuples? Did you want to call that function separately for each of the tuples in the list? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Ill add the function to the question, two secs, sorry its not clear

Comment: Again, an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and shows us what you expected to happen instead would make your question a *lot* clearer.

Comment: Okay I've tried to make it clearer, hope that helps!

Comment: Your function *prints*, it doesn't return anything; the two concepts are quite distinct. So what's wrong with a loop over that list, and calling the function for each element in the list?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think of that, I'm relatively new to python as you can probably tell :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the tuples separately you can use a list comprehension:

```
[delimiter.join(x) for x in list_of_tup] # delimiter should be a string
```

Otherwise you need to unpack the tuples then join them all. Which for that aim you can use a nested list comprehension or `itertools.chain`:

```
delimiter.join([item for tup in list_of_tup for item in tup])
```